# Drawing triangles like it is 1980 but with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, pixel

How can I draw a triangle with modern OpenGL, that clearly shows pixels (filled rectangles) on diagonal lines?

What I have done so far:

1. Setup OpenGL (with GLEW) window in 320 x 200
2. Define vertices for the triangle:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
  0, 0, 0,
  320, 0, 0,
  320, 200, 0,
};
```

3. Create vertexbuffer, adding it to a vertex array, creating an index buffer, binding them and drawing to the screen with `glDrawElements`.
4. (Before drawing them) compile and attach a shader program consisting of a basic vertex- and fragment shader code. The fragment shader just outputs white color for each fragment, the vertex shader looks like this:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
uniform mat4 pr_matrix;

void main() {
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * position;
}
```

5. I am feeding it with the uniform matrix4. Which is just an orthographic projection matrix with `left: 0`, `bottom: 0`, `right: 320`, `top: 200`, `near: -1`, `far: 1`.

What I get is a triangle 320px wide and 200 px high. If I resize the window I call `glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);` (which does not resizes the triangle in correct aspect ratio, but that is OK for now ...).

But the triangle is rendered in the same resolution as my computer runs (1920, 1080) - I cannot see any zooming (of pixels). How can I achieve, that pixels are magnified so I get the impression the resolution is very low?

Comment: Have you tried rendering to a smaller render target, then sampling that render target, magnified, to draw it to the screen?

Comment: What do you mean by sampling that target? Make a texture of it? No, I haven't tried it. That could be a solution as long as this is an option for being done for each shape many times a second while rendering. After a time of research and thinking I also have the feeling, that my approach is not the best. Perhaps I should "simulate" the pixelated drawing with real squares.

Comment: Games very frequently render to render targets and sample them as textures many times a frame. This is how shadow mapping, reflection probes, VR lens distortion, bloom, temporal anti-aliasing, and many other common features are implemented. It's also very commonplace for it to be used to simulate a lower-resolution display for retro games, as you seem to be asking about here.

Comment: Create a renderBuffer with attached frameBuffer (FB). Then create textures for at least one of RGBA, depth, stencil. Set the FB texture res to (320 by 200) (ensure lookup is nearest or it will blur when upscaling). Bind FB and render scene as normal. Unbind FB and render FB texture to window (as quad). Note To maintain aspect, scale quad to fill window (some edge pixels will be lost), or set aspect when rendering to FB. Is Very easy to add to existing rendering system. https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferRenderbuffer.xml has all the links you will need